# Strings or URI in .NET APIs?

Tags: .net, api-design

I am writing an .NET wrapper API for the Netflix API.

At this point I can choose to represent URLs as either strings or URI objects. Seems to me there is a good case for both.

So if you were using an API, which would you prefer?

Comment: Care to share the cases you could make for both?

Answer (score 17):

The below quote is from: [Framework Design Guildelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321246756) 
I **highly** recommend this book to anyone developing frameworks on .Net

> **Do use** System.Uri to represent URI / URL data.
>  (For Parameters,
>   properties, and return values)
>
> System.Uri is a much safer and richer
>   way of representing URIs. Extensive
>   manipulation of URI-related data using
>   plain strings has been shown to cause
>   many security and correctness
>   problems.
>
> **Consider** providing string-based overloads for most commonly used
>   members with System.Uri parameters.
>
> In cases where the usage pattern of
>   taking a string from a user will be
>   common enough, you should consider
>   adding a convenience overload
>   accepting a string. The string-based
>   overload should be implemented in
>   terms of the Uri-based overload.
>
> **Do Not** automatically overload all Uri-based members with a version that
>   accepts a string.
>
> Generally, Uri-based APIs are
>   preferred. String-based overloads are
>   meant to be helpers for the most
>   common scenarios. Therefore, you
>   should not automatically provide
>   string-based overloads for all
>   variants of the Uri-based members. Be
>   selective and provide such helpers
>   just for the most commonly used
>   variants.

**EDIT (per comments):** The book specifically states: **"Extensive manipulation of URI-related data using plain strings has been shown to cause many security and correctness problems."** I am not sure what additional justification you want for using System.Uri / UriBuilder. Additionally, why wouldn't you want to take advantage of the framework to read/manipulate a URI?

When designing an API that will be used by others it is important to make them approachable, **as well as reliable**. For this reason the book does mention, you should provide "nice" overloads for common functionality. However, to ensure correctness, you should always implement the underlying code with URIs.

Can you please clarify your wants, or reasons to use only strings?

Comment: Bonus point for providing the link to the book, which I didn't know until now.

Comment: But why? I've read the book and it doesn't actually justify that decision.

Comment: You ask, "why wouldn't you want to take advantage of the framework to read/manipulate a URI?". Well, most of the framework-supplied functions for manipulating URIs work on string, not System.Uri. That realization is what prompted this question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that you should represent it as URI. However, if I am a user of your API and I am having to continuously convert string based URLs to URI to use your API, then I would be a pissed off user.

What I am saying is that you need to assess what kind of audience will be consuming your API.

Comment: Why use a URI? What does it really give you?

Answer (score 0):

One thing I found was that while writing `string`-accepting methods, I'd always have to initialize a `Uri` object anyway just to validate the string, such that the `UriFormatException` would then propagate out of the method if the user passed a bad string. But if you accept `Uri`s only, as I did after getting yelled at (rightfully) by FxCop, then you always know your input is valid---which to me seems like a very good sign that you're designing your API correctly.

Comment: As it happens, I know all my urls are correct because they are either generated by me or given to me by a trusted source.

So aside from validation, does it actually give you anything?

Comment: Well, it gives you the same thing that accepting an "int" when you desire an integer (as opposed to a string, then calling int.Parse) gives you.