# Should I use System.Net.Mail.MailAddress in my domain model, or just strings?

Tags: .net, api-design, domain-model, mailaddress

As covered well in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214746/strings-or-uri-in-net-apis), `System.Uri` is a good choice to reflect my intention for URIs. But what about for email addresses?

It seems not as clear-cut, because `MailAddress` has extra information in its `DisplayName` property that is not a great fit.

Comment: You don't have to use every bit of information provided by the MailAddress class. I would consider it pretty minimal overhead for the assurance of having well formed email addresses everywhere in your domain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't have to use the `DisplayName` if you don't want or need to. The `MailAddress` type ensures that an email address is well formed by throwing an exception in it's constructor otherwise. I would argue that it is worth using `MailAddress` over `String` for this reason and also because it communicates intent and adds little overhead.

Answer (score 1):

System.Uri has a lot of useful functionality, but System.Net.Mail.MailAddress doesn't, so whether to use it is not a critical decision. FWIW, I have implemented it both ways (but in different places!) -- string and MailAddress.